# how to save / load the state of a game in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm creating the game of chess in scheme, but do not know how to save and load game state is a part I have this code

```
(define-struct piece(color nove? type ))
;;tablero lista de listas de  fichas
(define-struct estado (board turn fichaSel))


(define bpawn (bitmap "b-peon.png"))
(define brook (bitmap "b-torre.png"))
(define bcaballo (bitmap "b-caballo.png"))
(define bbish (bitmap "b-arfil.png"))
(define bquee (bitmap "b-reina.png"))
(define bking (bitmap "b-rey.png"))
(define wpawn (bitmap "w-peon.png"))
(define wrook (bitmap "w-torre.png"))
(define wcaballo (bitmap "w-caballo.png"))
(define wbish (bitmap "w-arfil.png"))
(define wquee (bitmap "w-reina.png"))
(define wking (bitmap "w-rey.png"))
(define board (bitmap "board.jpg"))
```

This is the board that is a list of lists

```
(define board1 (list (list torreb caballob arfilb reinab reyb arfilb caballob torreb)
                       (list peonb peonb peonb peonb peonb peonb peonb peonb)
                       (list empty empty empty empty empty empty empty empty)
                       (list empty empty empty empty empty empty empty empty)
                       (list empty empty empty empty empty empty empty empty)
                       (list empty empty empty empty empty empty empty empty)
                       (list pawnw  pawnw  pawnw  pawnw  pawnw  pawnw  pawnw  pawnw)
                       (list rookw knightw bishopw queenw kingw bishopw knightw rookw)))
```

I did this to save the state of the game:

```
(define (save file)
(write-file (string-append Subcarpeta archivo ".txt")
               "game state"  ))
```

But not as you insert the game state on "game state" for me to save the game

How I can do this ?

Comment: Is this Racket? I would assume there is some serialize procedure you can use.

Comment: Yes, is racket. What process  I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The terminoligy in both Scheme and Racket for what is known as a file handle in the OS and other programming languages are port.

You have [lots of possibilities](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html?q=write&q=racket%20IO&q=open-file&q=with-port&q=port&q=write%20&q=with&q=with-open-file) of course but none of this is supported in the Beginner to Intermediate student with lambda languages. With Advanced student you have these options:

```scm
#!htdp/asl

(with-output-to-file "file.rc"
    (lambda () (write '(your data structure))))

(with-input-from-file "file.rc"
    (lambda () (read)))            ; ==> (your data structure)
```

The problem with this is that you'll get an error if the file exists. With `#!racket` you can add flags to overcome this:

```scm
#!racket

(with-output-to-file "file.rc"
    (lambda () (write '(your data structure)))
    #:mode 'text
    #:exists 'truncate)

(with-input-from-file "file.rc"
    (lambda () (read)))            ; ==> (your data structure)
```

Comment: Thanks but I try to do in the intermediate  student  language, as could do?

Comment: @user3672728 You haven't written anywhere in your question what language you are using so I assumed `#!racket`. For next time, specify language! The only student language that has I/O is advances student so you need to switch.

Comment: I did this but it returns this error: `with-output-to-file: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 2 plus optional arguments with keywords #:exists and #:mode
  given: 6
  arguments...:
   "file.rc"
   (lambda () ...)
   '#:mode
   'text
   '#:exists
   'truncate
`

Comment: @user3672728 Advanced student donæt allow keyword parameters. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but #! Racket returns me this error `read: #! not enabled in the current context`, then  I can not work this in advanced student or I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `#!xxx`-notation works when you select "Determine language from source" in the bottom left select box in DrRacket. `#!htdp/asl` is  the Advanced student and #!racket is the Racket language. `#!r6rs` is Scheme standard and `#!r5rs` is legacy Scheme standard. `#!racket` is short for `#lang racket` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, throws me the error exists, there is no other way to do it? 
working with advanced student

Comment: I'm afraid not. Is there a specific reason why you want to use the student languages? Your code works in #!racket too.

Comment: because this language if they ask me to create the game

Comment: Questions as I do to load the board as you save?

Comment: @user3672728 my code saves to file then reads it back. You can use the result as the board or set! it to load.

Comment: as I can get the state of the game that I want to save hear  `; ==> (your data structure)`

Comment: Yes. The second expression reads the file that is created in the first expression. You may want to make procedures that has file and data (in the store function) as variables.

Comment: yes, but as I can I get my structure, I do not understand :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say but you can either pass the result to whatever your chess program uses to start up or you can store the result.. like `(set! board1 (get-config))` where `get-config` is the last code wrapped in a procedure.

Comment: I've been trying to save the game but do not know what I put in the  `get-config`